# Form disappears when I call ajax in response to a button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have some text and a file control and a button and an image which all disappear when the button is clicked and I call an ajax request from there. I checked all the other stack overflow answers and all the other sites, but doing anything including inserting a hidden field, or adding the missing code with PHP or JS all don't work. Thank you very much for your help.

```
<div id = "CreatePostUpload">                                       
    Select Image to Upload:
    <input type='file' name='CreatePostImageFile' id = "CreatePostImageFile" />
    <input type='button' onclick = "uploadCreatePostPhoto()" value='Save' name='but_upload' id = "CreatePostImageSubmit" />
    <img src="images/cancel.png" onclick="closeCreatePostUploadPhoto()"/>
</div>
```

Everything inside the CreatePostUpload div disappears when I call the following:

```
function uploadCreatePostPhoto() {
                                                    
        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = $('#CreatePostImageFile')[0].files[0];
        fd.append('file', files);
                                               
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadMyCreatePostPhoto.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
                                                                 
                 $("#CreatePostUpload").html(response);
                 closeCreatePostUploadPhoto();
            },
    });
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: because you replace the content..... `$("#CreatePostUpload").html(response);`

Answer (score 0):

[epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello), who posted [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169261/form-disappears-when-i-call-ajax-in-response-to-a-button/68169448#comment120481460_68169261)

> because you replace the content..... `$("#CreatePostUpload").html(response);`

is right: I was replacing my content.

Comment: In the case when there *is* no answer and the thanks are directed at a commenter, a suitable course of action is to edit the answer to add attribution and quote the content.